# Dataset/datasource Winform VB project using ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, reportviewer

We are trying to figure out how the ReportViewer works and are stuck at the dataset/datasource part. We have a sql-query that connects with 3 different Servers. Is there a simple way to connect a rdlc report to such a dataset in a winform Project that will be shown in Report Viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a ReportDataSource object to the LocalReport.DataSources Property. The constructor take two parameters.

First the name of the dataset (as it is defined in the rdlc repport), second a datasource object which could be any .Net Collection (ADO.Net DataSet or a simple List of object).

The mapping to the field declared is done in the same way than DataBinding. Just have the same name for the column of the ADO.Net DataSet or the property of the object in the list than the field in the report.

Take a look at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.aspx